# Vue + Webpack + Meteor Client Side

Tags: meteor, webpack, vue.js

I want integrate meteor-client-side from NPM in a vue.js Webpack project.
The project is generated with vueCli.

This is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
require('meteor-client-side')

console.log(Meteor.status())
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
})
```

With console.log i get a eslint error 'Meteor is not defined', but when i try Meteor.status() on the browser console it works fine.

What i doing wrong?

I don't want use vue in meteor, i need meteor-client-side in this non meteor project.

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var Meteor = require('meteor-client-side');

console.log(Meteor.status())
```

If you want to use a node module in the code you need to assign it to a variable, like `var $ = require('jquery');`.  But if the JS just does things on its own and you don't need a reference to it, you can just require it, so like:

```
var $ = var jQuery = require('jquery');  //sets $ to jquery
require('bootstrap');                    //just extends jquery, no need to save reference
```